# Vb.net - Setting a controls margin value

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls, margin

So, I'm adding a label programatically and I'm in need of altering the top margin a little bit to the value 8. I can't do that the obvious way, so what's wrong with my thinking?

```
Dim LabelAdapter As New Label
LabelAdapter.text = "Adapter"
LabelAdapter.Margin.Top = 8
```

This gives me the error "Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Label.Margin` returns a [`Padding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.padding.aspx) object.

Since `Padding` is a structure, it will actually return a *copy*. You are changing the `Top` value of that copy, not of the actual control’s margin. Since that would have no noticeable effect, VB correctly prevents it.

You need to assign a whole new margin. In fact, the `Margin` property (or rather, the `Padding` class) is arguably broken since it doesn’t allow an easy way to change the individual values.

Unfortunately, we just have to live with it. So to change just the `Top` value, we need to write:

```
Dim old As Padding = LabelAdapter.Margin
LabelAdapter.Margin = New Padding(old.Left, 8, old.Right, old.Bottom)
```

Weird, huh?

Comment: If Intellisense is not suggesting you the Padding class, ignore it, more often that not it will work; btw why does this happen?

Comment: @WeaponX I don’t understand your comment.

Comment: At least using VB.NET the IDE (2013) will not suggest you some classes like Padding until you write the entire name.

Comment: @WeaponX Okay, but I’m not sure how that’s relevant here. It may imply a bug in their suggestion heuristic. Or not, I have no idea.